# How to get the distance to a place from an FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm working on a custom EditText autocomplete and I'd like to get the distance between my current location and the received place from the [FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest) too.
As a response I get an [AutocompletePrediction](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompletePrediction) which is containing a ***getDistanceMeters()*** method, but it's always null.

The documentation says that the ***getDistanceMeters()*** will return null if a **origin** is not provided in the request. The problem is that I'm providing a origin and I'm still getting a null from that method.

Here is my code:

```
LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(36.376232, 28.380365);

// My request where I included the origin LatLng
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                // Set the current location to get the distance
                .setOrigin(currentLocation)
                .setLocationBias(bounds)
                //.setLocationRestriction(bounds)
                .setCountry("ro")
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                .setSessionToken(token)
                .setQuery(searchString.toString())
                .build();
```

Getting the response:

```
placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener(response -> {
        for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
            // Getting NULL 
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(prediction.getDistanceMeters()));
        }
    })
```

I'm getting the places, but not the distances from origin. Is there something that I'm missing?